# How can I put some memory section in particular memory

Tags: gcc, memory, arm, ld

I am trying to understand the GCC link script and create a small demo to practice , however I got the "syntax error" from ld. I appreciate any comments or suggestions. Thank you so much!

hello.c

```
__attribute__((section(".testsection"))) volatile int testVariable;
```

hello.ld

```
MEMORY {
  TEST_SECTION: ORIGIN = 0x43840000 , LENGTH = 0x50    
}
SECTIONS{
.testsection: > TEST_SECTION /* Syntax error here*/
}
```

compile command

```
gcc -T hello.ld -o hello hello.o
c:/gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe:../hello.ld:20: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: did you try  .testsection : { *(.testsection*) } > TEST_SECTION

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried .testsection : { *(.testsection) } > TEST_SECTION, I didn't get an error, but .I still got the same error with testsection : { (.testsection) } > TEST_SECTION . I am not sure .testsection : { *(.testsection) } > TEST_SECTION is the correct way to do that.

Comment: .text : { \*(.text*) } > rom
is what I use for .text, .rodata, .bss, etc in mine and they work perfectly so thought I would toss that out there.  did you read the gnu linker documentation?  hmmm maybe some formatting happened to the comment there is asterisk which your reply shows in front of the parenthesis. and now it shows the asterisk

Comment: rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
how about a comma between origin value and length?  the error message is telling you what line the problem is on

Comment: you didnt indicate which line ld was complaining about.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks for your correction, There is a comma in the code. currently there is no syntax error now with .testsection : { *(.testsection) } > TEST_SECTION. not sure whether it is a correct way.

Comment: perhaps you had two issues, always start by looking at the error message including line number.  starting with the first error if there are multiple

Comment: @old_timer I updated the post and add "error " location.

Comment: so you still get the error without the { bracketed } part?

Comment: @old_timer Yes, I read it, so I think  .sectionname : { *(.sectionname) } > regionname, it's the solution for that. but not sure

Comment: I dont think .sectionname : > regionname is allowed from the documentation I think you have to put { something }  in there, perhaps try .testsection : { } > TEST_SECTION?  but that may end up not putting anything in TEST_SECTION if it builds without error then confirm what is actually in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original post

```
MEMORY {
  TEST_SECTION: ORIGIN = 0x43840000 LENGTH = 0x50    
}
SECTIONS{
.testsection: > TEST_SECTION
}
```

### Solution

```
MEMORY {
  TEST_SECTION: ORIGIN = 0x43840000, LENGTH = 0x50    
}
SECTIONS{
.testsection: { *(.testsection*) } > TEST_SECTION
}
```

I think it was missing two things.

First the comma between the origin value and LENGTH.

Second a section command was missing. I don't think the GNU linker script syntax allows for that, you probably need to put something in there anyway to have this be useful.  You could try

```
.testsection: { } > TEST_SECTION
```

but my guess without trying it is that you wouldn't end up with anything in that memory.

### Edit

After doing an experiment:

so.s

```
.text
add r0,r0,r0
add r1,r2,r3
add r1,r1,r1
add r2,r2,r2
```

so.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .hello : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .world : { } > ted
    .text : { } > ted
}

Disassembly of section .hello:

30000000 <.hello>:
30000000:   e0800000    add r0, r0, r0
30000004:   e0821003    add r1, r2, r3
30000008:   e0811001    add r1, r1, r1
3000000c:   e0822002    add r2, r2, r2
```

As I suspected, first I already new the names in MEMORY are whatever you want, as you saw as well, RAM, ROM, etc are not special names just can't use reserved names if any. I suspected that SECTIONS worked the same way the thing on the left is a new name you are creating for the output.  This built and linked just fine (not a real program obviously just enough to get the tools to do a demonstration).

The linker did not complain, but at the same time since there was nothing actually placed in ted then nothing was placed in that memory space in the output binary.  .hello and .text don't have to match, one is an output name one is an input name, very often for simple stuff folks make them match, why create a new name.  Only did it here for demonstration purposes to show that by using the same name on the left does not automatically include the input section to the output.

I highly recommend doing experiments like this and using tools like readelf and objdump and others to examine what is going on (as well as reading the documentation for the scripting language).

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. learned a lot from it. Actually I am trying to port greenhills ld file to GCC link script . I created this small simple to show one issue here . Could you kindly please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733509/greenhills-link-script-to-gcc-link-script-porting-for-arm-target? , Actually , I found more after doing some more exploration.